# A fee of 1000$ is requested to get refunded from Blockchain

Tags: investing, trading, scams, cryptocurrency

Good Morning all,

I hope to get an answer to this question.
**I have been scammed from cryptocurrency platform**. I have received many calls of people who wants to help me recover my money.
Recently, I have been called by another company called  [scam site redacted]. They told me that to recover my money I just need to deposit equivalent of 1000$ of BTC on my wallet and wait for about two hours and then my money which frozen on the Blockchain will be released and send to me in my wallet. According to them, this amoount of money is to fight against money laundry.
Even if, They cannot remove that money from my wallet, I am still worry about this.

**Is there someone who knows about this practice?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a scam. What they are suggesting is not possible. They are likely the same people who scammed you the first time. Scam link removed.

Comment: Is it a normal procedure that to recover your money from blockchain, you should have at least 1000$ of BTC?

Comment: It is literally impossible to do what they are suggesting. It would require 51% of all blockchain miners [which is mostly a half a dozen massive server farms worth billions of dollars] to agree to reverse the transaction. They are lying to you and scamming you. For your own sake, consider walking away from anything crypto related forever.

Comment: YOU HAVE BEEN SCAMMED.  DON'T LET THEM SCAM YOU AGAIN. Sorry for shouting, but it seems you have not learned your lesson yet. The money is gone. Take it as a learning experience and move on. DO NOT ENGAGE any more in that type of thing.

Comment: It seem you can't recognize a scam even after being a victim of one. Therefore, you should walk away from all of this. If you think it's a scam, it's a scam. No second thoughts. You might think "*but what if it's the one time it's not a scam?" No. It's a scam 99.99% of the time, which means it might as well be 100% of the time. Don't get greedy. You're far more likely to lose than to gain.

Answer (score 8):

You're a perfect victim.  They know it.  So they're working you again.

You say "many DIFFERENT people" have been calling you offering to help get your money back.  How would they know you lost any money?  Only the scammer knows this.

Those "other people" are *in fact, the same scammer AGAIN*.

Your name is now being passed around amongst different people at the scam company, and they're all taking a swing at you.  They like to put their effort where it has the best chance for success, and a prior scam victim is likely to be weak-minded and fall for it again. It's just business, nothing personal.

You were careless.  Now, cut your losses, walk away and NEVER FORGET.

And by the way... in the future... almost ANYONE who calls you with an offer or a threat is ripping you off. HANG UP.

- Say someone says "they're coming over to arrest you unless you pay your back taxes in iTunes gift cards" - that's a flat scam.
- They say they're from AT&T and want to sell you better Internet service - say no and HANG UP.  But then, research the various internet providers' prices - Comcast, Verizon, Charter, and sure why not - AT&T.  Find the one you like the most and switch.
- If a caller says "we want to make you aware of a government program that could benefit you", then take some notes, HANG UP, and then go research independently via government sites only, and see if that program really exists and if you qualify.
- Never use a phone number or web address they gave you. That's likely to be a fake.

When you take action *on your own initiative*, you get the best deal and the best protection.  When someone calls you and you agree to it, you always get a worse deal.

Now there's a longshot possibility that the caller might have a *slightly* better deal than you could get on your own... but that is highly unlikely, and the deal would be barely better, so **it is not worth the risk**.

Comment: And literally hang up. Don't try to ask questions and investigate if it's real if you already have a past history and ongoing record of getting fooled.

Answer (score 4):

> I have been scammed from cryptocurrency platform. Recently, I have
> been called by another company called [scam site redacted].

This is a scam.  Stolen cryptocurrency is impossible to recover.